# Calculus(Convergence/Divergence of series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

May I know how to use the ratio test and the comparison test to test for convergence for this question.

$$\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (K^{\frac{1}{k}}-1)^{2k}
\end{equation}$$
For the comparison test, I do not know which term to compare with, how to find which term to compare with?

Comment: what was your summation equation? is it
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (K^{\frac{1}{k}}-1)^{2k}
\end{equation}
what was the range of $K$? I suppose $K>0$?

Comment: @user124358: K is from 1 to infinity

Comment: @user124358: Yup K more than 0

Comment: @yswong K and k are different?

Comment: @user124358: Its the same k.

Comment: @yswong: the question should be updated to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $k\ge3$, $k^{1/k}-1\le\sqrt[3]3-1$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(k^{1/k}-1\right)^{2k}
\le(\sqrt2-1)^4+\sum_{k=3}^\infty\left(\sqrt[3]3-1\right)^{2k}
$$
The right hand side is a geometric series.